# Legendary smith problems

Tags: final-fantasy-3

I have been playing Final Fantasy 3 (FF3) for about 33 hours now (I have played three times previously) but I am now having trouble with the legendary smith to get the ultima sword.

I have talked to the Princess, fixed her amulet and returned it. I have also exterminated the pest in the basement and received the ore. I have talked to Cid for the cut scene and completed up to the big light tower thingy as I have defeated everyone up to this point.

I have searched in all the smith's spawns including that dark knight village where I have seen other people go for this sword but it has not spawned.

What am I missing? What should I do to get the Ultima Sword?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is explained on the [FF3 Legendary Smith wikia page](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_Smith), especially:

> ## Finding the Smith
>
> ### Restore Princess Sara's Pendant
>
> The party will receive a message from Princess Sara about her pendant (the player will have to check
>   Mognet as Ingus), and the player must visit Castle Sasune: East Tower
>   to Princess Sara's room and she will give the player the pendant. It
>   has recently become broken, and needs repairing.
>
> The party then needs to visit Takka to have it repaired and he will
>   claim it is beyond his abilities. Regardless, in his mail (which the
>   player will have to check Mognet as Refia) he informs them of the
>   Legendary Smith whom they must find in North Western Saronia. She
>   repairs the pendant and in return she asks the party to find her some
>   Orichalcum. Return the pendant to Princess Sara in her tower.
>
> ### Find Orichalcum
>
> Check Mognet as Luneth to find a message from Cid titled "Something in the Basement...". Visit Cid in Canaan and
>   talk to him to hear about the monster. Head down to Cid's basement and
>   defeat the Aeon to collect an "Unknown Metal". Talk to Cid once more
>   and he'll identify it as Orichalcum.
>
> Now take the Orichalcum to the Legendary Smith, in Falgabard, after
>   unlocking the door in Eureka. Upon giving her the metal, she will
>   provide the Ultima Weapon, and wander the world.

A list of locations is also available, where you can find the Legendary Smith:

> - Ur - Inside the well.
>   - Castle Sasune - The East Tower's third floor.
>   - Healing Copse - The grove just before Tozus.
>   - Village of the Ancients - The Inn.
>   - Gysahl - Inside the Chocobo stable.
>   - Replito - A northern house.
>   - Dwarven Hollows - The entrance to the Subterranean Lake.
>   - Saronia Castle - The basement.
>   - Doga's Village - The central island.
>   - Ancient Ruins - The Inn.
>   - Saronia Castle - The hidden passageway in the left area where the two Black Mages are.